# Aptana Studio 3: How to get Syntax Highlighting of Shell Scripts *.sh

Tags: shell, aptana, codehighlighter, syntaxhighlighter

Is there any "Formatter" / syntanx highlighting for linux shell script available for Aptana Studio 3 ?!?

I did find "shelled" but this seems only to work with eclipse and not aptana studio 3 standalone (and i could not get it to work in eclipse either)

Just simple plain syntax highlighting for *.sh files anyone?!?

Answer (score 0):

Try ShellEd (http://shelled.sourceforge.net/project-info.html). It has worked pretty well for me.